# Solving an LP greedily

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, combinatorics

I have the following LP:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{Minimize} & \sum_{j=1}^n x_j \\
\text{Subject to} & \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_j \geq b_i,~~~i\in\{1,\ldots,M\} \\
                  & 0 \leq x_j \leq 1,~~~j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}
\end{array}
$$
where all $a_{ij} \geq 0, \forall i,j$ and $b_i \geq 0,\forall i$, and these are known.

I am looking for a quick *direct* solution for this LP if it exists. We know that $n$ is much smaller than $M$. This seems similar to the fractional multi-Knapsack problem. I am wondering if there exists a greedy solution that I can use.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered just solving the dual of the LP? Or equivalently using the dual simplex method on the LP?  If $n$ is quite small, then this should be very fast to solve.

Comment: I think @BrianBorchers is asking the right question: this is just a standard linear problem (possibly with many constraints) for which efficient methods are widely available. The dual problem can reduce the number of linear constraints coming from $Ax\ge b$ from $M$ to $n$ if $M$ is too large.

Comment: Do you really need an exact solution, or would you be interested in approximation algorithms that give feasible solutions with a bound on how far from optimal they might be?  Would you be interested in probabilistic algorithms that might produce solutions that don't precisely satisfy the constraints?  Are you interested in online algorithms that allow you to add additional constriants or variables on the fly?  How big are $M$ and $n$ in your problem instances?  How fast a solution do you need?